# Настройки поля формы в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Было:

```
<?= $form->field($form_model, 'email') ?>
```

Нашёл решение, сделал:

```
<?= $form->field($form_model, 'email', ['inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']])->textInput()->input('email', ['placeholder' => "Enter Your Email"])->label(false); ?>
```

placeholder работает, autofocus работает, вроде всё нормально но осталось пара вопросов, хочется разобраться:

1. Зачем мы делаем `->textInput()` а потом ещё раз `->input`
2. Название поля `'email'` стало употребляться 2 раза, зачем?
3. Что такое `->label(false)` в конце. За что отвечает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не к чему, что-то лишние. Попробуйте убрать одно из двух.
2. Результат выполнения 2-х функций `textInput` и `input`
3. `label` Выводит тайтл поля, если передается false то тайтла не будет, к примеру:

```html
<div class="form-group field-banner-url has-success">
<label class="control-label" for="banner-url">Url</label>
<input type="text" id="banner-url" class="form-control" name="Banner[url]" maxlength="255" aria-invalid="false">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```